# Show a div only when a value = 0

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with this script.

The script shows to me the hidden div `#regalo` if `#total` is between **99.99** and **299.99** ... ok, but (now), I also need to show the hidden div `#alert` when `#total` is 0 (zero), **and be available to show if values ​​of #total more than 1** , and only when the screen is in landscapeand mode...

Truth is that I can't find a way to modify the code.

Any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
function manageRegalo() {

var totalStorage = Number(localStorage.getItem("total"));
var total = parseFloat($("#total").val());

if (totalStorage != null && total === 0) {
  total = totalStorage;
}

if(total > 99.99 && total < 299.99) {
  console.log("PASS");
  $('#regalo').show();

 //if(total === 0) {
 //if(total == 0) {
 //if(total < 1) {
 //$('#alert').hide();
 //}

 //else{
 //$('#alert').show();
 //};

if (localStorage.getItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1') == null) {
  $('.tooltip').show();
    window.setTimeout(function() {
  $('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
    }, 9000);

//--------------------

if (!$("#notify")[0].paused) { //play audio
  $("#notify")[0].pause(); //play audio
  $("#notify")[0].currentTime = 0; //play audio

} else {  // play audio
  setTimeout(function() { //play audio
  $("#notify")[0].play(); //play audio
  })}; //play audio

//--------------------

  localStorage.setItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1', 'true')
  }

 } else {
  console.log("FAIL");
  $('#regalo').hide();
}
}

$(document).on('click', function(event) {
const target = event.target;
if (target.matches('.comp-clone') || target.matches('.bbp')) {
  manageRegalo();

localStorage.setItem('total', Number($("#total").val()));
}
});
manageRegalo();
});
```

```css
  #alert {
  display: none
}

@media screen and (max-width:999px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  #alert {
    display: block !important
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="regalo"></div>
<div id="alert"></div>
<!-- I need to show this div when the #total equals zero -->
```

Comment: First off, consistent indentation will make your code *much* more readable, not only for us but also for you to help you understand and modify your code.  Once you do that, what part has you confused?  Do you see where the "total" is compared to "99.99" and "299.99"?  Do you see where "regalo" is "shown"?  What happens when you try to do the same thing for "alert"?

Comment: @mplungjan ... I am a rookie in JS. I've tried several ways to show the hidden div `#regalo` when `#total` is = 0 but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Your code seems to work. https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/L3nxf7uy/ what is the issue? I had to comment out the localStorage stuff for the fiddle. I moved the function out of the ready because it does not need to live there

Comment: @Pablo_Web: Start with what you tried and in what way it didn't work. To better understand how this community can help, you are encouraged to review this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask At a high level, in general a question is expected to be in the form of "Here is what I did and here is the part that isn't working as expected". Yours is in the form of "I give up, someone please do it for me." If the problem is that a specific operation is producing an unexpected result, we can help with that. If the problem is that you don't know JavaScript at all, there are tutorials for that.

Comment: @mplungjan ... Yes. My script works perfectly, but as you can see the div `#alert` is not hidden when the value of `#total` = 0. I made some adjustments, but it doesn't work for me either. See: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/huqwb8fm/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This is where consistent and sensible indentation is important.  All of the conditions you're trying are all valid:

```
if (total === 0)
if (total == 0)
if (total < 1)
```

Any one of them by itself will work just fine.  But the problem is that they're not by themselves.  They're inside another condition:

```
if (total > 99.99 && total < 299.99)
```

When *that* condition is true, *none* of your above conditions can possibly be true.  The same variable (`total`) can not be greater than 99.99 *and* equal to 0 at the same time.

Don't put the test for zero inside of that `if` block:

```
if (total > 99.99 && total < 299.99) {

    if (total === 0) {
        //...
    }

}
```

Put it *outside* of that `if` block:

```
if (total > 99.99 && total < 299.99) {
    //...
}

if (total === 0) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with this

```js
function manageRegalo() {
  var totalStorage = Number(localStorage.getItem("total")) || 0;
  var total = parseFloat($("#total").val());
  if (totalStorage && total === 0) {
    total = totalStorage;
  }
  $('#regalo').toggle(total > 99.99 && total < 299.99);
  $("#alert").toggle(!total);

  if ($('#regalo').is(":visible") && localStorage.getItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1')!="true") {
    $('.tooltip').show();
    localStorage.setItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1',"true");
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
    }, 9000);
  }
}
```